# Substitute for deprecated register_globals in php5 for updating path variables used by exec?

Tags: php, linux, shell, scripting, environment-variables

I am using php as a command line scripting language for executing various system commands.

The directive 'register_globals' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater.

**What is a clean way to update the PATH environment variable that is used by the exec command?**

The following seems to throw away the value of PATH after the exec command finishes:

```
exec('PATH=$PATH:"' . $app_path .'"; export PATH' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putenv() does this:

```
putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':' . $app_path);
```

You can get environment variables with [`getenv()`](http://php.net/getenv) and set them with [`putenv()`](http://php.net/putenv).

Comment: Thanks - works great! I had tried putenv before, but was attempting to get the path via $_ENV, which required register_globals.

Answer (score 0):

Besides getenv(), you can access it from `$_SERVER["PATH"]`.

The `$_ENV` array is usually empty, due to the missing in `E` in the `variables_order=GPCS` configuration setting. (Has nothing to do with register_globals, but it's a related issue.)